# hex variables in python

Tags: python, arrays, variables, hex

I am defining a byte array in python and the same value shows up multiple times and I would like to replace that value by a variable.
Here's an example of a similar code:

```
btarray = bytearray([
    0xa9, 0x01,
    0x6d, 0x01
])
```

I want to, instead of writing 0x01 all the time, just write x, might the following be working?

```
x = 0x01

btarray = bytearray([
    0xa9, x,
    0x6d, x
])
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know how to easily monitor the array

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by "replace the value 0x01 by a variable named x", can you elaborate?

Comment: instead of writing 0x01 every time I could just write "x" instead

Comment: Still not 100% clear. Are you referring to the value of `x`, or `x` as a sign, a letter?

Comment: x is the variable's name

Comment: Yes I know it is. What isn't clear to me is what you are referring to when you say `x`. Can you provide another example, maybe? Is your question about creating arrays, or modifying them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood your question! The answer is **yes**! Unfortunately I don't have any documentation to link to, since this is quite basic and low-level.

Comment: Probably, I cant test or rugit now

Comment: @Spyro999 Take a look here, if you want: https://repl.it/repls/KeenBlondScript.

Comment: Also @Spyro999 don’t forget to accept the answer if it solves the problem/answers your question!

Comment: I did with the first one who did

Comment: @Spyro999 Oh, but was what he answered actually your question?

Comment: Because right now that answer seems incorrect to me.

Comment: He did in the comments and now I changed it

Comment: @Spyro999 Alright, that’s what I thought. I got confused there lol